# Sum of ratio bounded by ratio of sum

Tags: number-theory, inequality, summation, fractions

I need your expertise in providing an upper bound for the following problem:

Given two sets of $n$ non negative real numbers $\{ a_i\}_{i=1}^n, \{ b_j\}_{j=1}^n$ where for every $i,j \in [n]$, $a_i,b_j \geq \frac{1}{2n}$, where $n > 1$, and $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n b_j \leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i$.

Can we prove that there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}_+$ such that
$$ 
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{b_i} \leq \frac{c\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^n b_j} ?
$$

If so, how we bound $c$ in any way?

Please advise and thanks in advance.

P.s. If the following can not be achieved, what are the necessary conditions that the sets of real number must apply in order to attain the desired bound?

Comment: Isn't it enough to take $$ c=\frac{\sum b_i \sum \frac{a_i}{b_i}}{\sum a_i} $$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b_i=\frac{1}{2n}$ and $a_i=1$.

Hence, we need $$2n^2\leq c\cdot\frac{n}{\frac{1}{2}}$$ or
$$c\geq n,$$
which says that needed $c$ does not exist.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, i have corrected the question!

Comment: @user3492773 I think it's not fair! I solved your problem and instead of to accept my answer and to open new topic, you changed the question.

Comment: I have incorrectly written the question, you answer is by far correct w.r.t. the older wrongly written question.

Comment: Why does it say that $c$ does not exist? (can you elaborate?)

Comment: @user3492773 Because for all $c\in\mathbb R$ there is $n$, for which $n>c$.